# Burning a bootloader onto my Arduino MEGA 2560 without another arduino board, or isp board

Tags: arduino-mega, bootloader

[My youtube video explains it.](https://youtu.be/Rzkvhx_ctbw) It's starting to get on my nerves.

Comment: Please explain your problem in text instead of a 4 minute video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a programmer (isp or Arduino board as programmer). It is not possible to burn a bootloader without it. The USBasp version 2 plus a 10 to 6 pin adapter cost about 2 dollars.